# Why is my element value not getting changed? Am I using the wrong function?

Tags: javascript, textbox

I have an asp.net mvc application and i am trying to assign value to my textbox dynamically, but it seems to be not working (I am only testing on IE right now). This is what I have right now..

`document.getElementsByName('Tue').Value = tue;` (by the way tue is a variable)

I have also tried this variation but it didnt work either.

`document.getElementsById('Tue').Value = tue;` (by the way tue is a variable)

Can someone where please tell me where I am going wrong with this?

Comment: Just to clarify because it's not immediately apparent from reading the answers, the correct code is: document.getElementById('Tue').value = 'BLAH';

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's [document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.getElementById), not document.getElementsByID

I'm assuming you have `<input id="Tue" ...>` somewhere in your markup.

Comment: u were right about the getElements its getElementByID and i had getElementsById  .. good catch thanx

Answer (score 23):

How to address your textbox depends on the HTML-code:

```
<!-- 1 --><input type="textbox" id="Tue" />
<!-- 2 --><input type="textbox" name="Tue" />
```

If you use the 'id' attribute:

```
var textbox = document.getElementById('Tue');
```

for 'name':

```
var textbox = document.getElementsByName('Tue')[0]
```

(Note that getElementsByName() returns *all* elements with the name as array, therefore we use [0] to access the first one)

Then, use the 'value' attribute:

```
textbox.value = 'Foobar';
```

Answer (score 5):

There are two issues in your code.

1. Use `getElementByName` instead of `getElement**s**ByName`
2. use the `value` in lowercase instead of `Value`.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Chrome, then debug with the console. Press SHIFT+CTRL+j to get the console on screen.

Trust me, it helps a lot.

Comment: "If you are using Chrome, then debug with the console. Press SHIFT+CTRL+j to get the console on screen." Must remember: SHIFT+CTRL+j

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like we need to assume that your textbox name and ID are both set to "Tue."  If that's the case, try using a lower-case V on .value.

Answer (score 4):

As the plural in `getElementsByName()` implies, does it always return list of elements that have this name. So when you have an input element with that name:

```
<input type="text" name="Tue">
```

And it is the first one with that name, you have to use `document.getElementsByName('Tue')[0]` to get the first element of the list of elements with this name.

Beside that are properties case sensitive and the correct spelling of the value property is `.value`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
formname.textboxname.value="delete";
```