# GetElementById.SetAttribute in web browser is not working It does not work

Tags: c#, visual-studio

https://www.paypal.com/myaccount/transfer/buy

There is a text box on this page
I want to write the string to Textbox.

But doesn't work.

```
  webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("recipient").SetAttribute("value","test@mail");
```

Plese help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am wondering what you are trying to achieve here ? but let's dissect your question into various pieces and see how it goes :

> There is a text box on this page

Alright, the link you shared contains two textboxes: one for email and the other for password. I assume you are referring to email textbox. Now 'id' attribute of email textbox is 'email' and not 'recipient' as suggested by your code. How do you find attributes associated with an element : see [here](http://testingfreak.com/inspect-element-in-firefox-chrome-or-ie-browsers/)

Next:

> I want to write the string to textbox

Here, There are two issues in your code:
Use `document.getElementById('email')` instead of webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById (please note the exact syntax including caps)

in order to assign string value to textbox use `document.getElementById('email').value = 'hey'`

Hope this answers your query !
Please research before posting questions there is an answer available to similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477543/how-do-i-assign-value-to-a-textbox-using-javascript)